# How to invoke layout to the child when parent constraints are not changed

Tags: flutter

I have a nested widget hierarchy in my project. What I am trying to do is, I have performed some calculations in the parent widget. Based on the calculation result, the visual range will vary. So, I want to layout the child through the parent layout to update its position and rendering. However, due to the fact that the parent constraints have not changed, the child layout won't occur.

Here I replicated this issue in simple sample and shared below.

```
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart';

void main() {
  return runApp(_App());
}

class _App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      home: _HomePage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class _HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  _HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<_HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Widget1(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

enum WidgetSlot { Widget }

class Widget1
    extends SlottedMultiChildRenderObjectWidget<WidgetSlot, RenderObject> {
  @override
  SlottedContainerRenderObjectMixin<WidgetSlot, RenderBox> createRenderObject(
      BuildContext context) {
    return RenderWidget1();
  }

  @override
  Widget? childForSlot(WidgetSlot slot) {
    return Widget2();
  }

  @override
  Iterable<WidgetSlot> get slots => WidgetSlot.values;
}

class RenderWidget1 extends RenderBox
    with SlottedContainerRenderObjectMixin<WidgetSlot, RenderBox> {
  RenderWidget1() {
    _tapGestureRecognizer = TapGestureRecognizer()..onTapUp = _handleTapUp;
  }

  late TapGestureRecognizer _tapGestureRecognizer;

  void _handleTapUp(TapUpDetails details) {
    markNeedsLayout();
  }

  @override
  bool hitTestSelf(Offset position) {
    return true;
  }

  @override
  void performLayout() {
    size = constraints.biggest;
    (childForSlot(WidgetSlot.Widget) as RenderWidget2).layout(constraints);
  }

  @override
  void handleEvent(PointerEvent event, covariant BoxHitTestEntry entry) {
    super.handleEvent(event, entry);
    if (event is PointerDownEvent) {
      _tapGestureRecognizer.addPointer(event);
    }
  }

  @override
  void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset offset) {
    context.canvas.drawRect(paintBounds, Paint()..color = Colors.red);
  }
}

class Widget2 extends LeafRenderObjectWidget {
  @override
  RenderObject createRenderObject(BuildContext context) {
    return RenderWidget2();
  }
}

class RenderWidget2 extends RenderBox {
  @override
  void performLayout() {
    print('2');
    size = constraints.biggest;
  }
}
```

Any solution to invoke child layout even when parent constraints are not changed?

After debugging the Flutter source, I figured out this code:
`if (!_needsLayout && constraints == _constraints) {`
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/object.dart#L2477. In this code, `_needsLayout` will be set to true when calling `markNeedsLayout`, but in my case, it cannot be done.

I tried marking `RenderWidget2` as repaint boundary too but it doesn't work.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Just curious: why using `SlottedMultiChildRenderObjectWidget` and custom `RenderBox` instead usual `Rows/Columns` and `Containers`? (I've never saw `SlottedMultiChildRenderObjectWidget` be used before)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you may call `markNeedsLayout` for the children on `_handleTapUp`, like this:

```dart
void _handleTapUp(TapUpDetails details) {
  markNeedsLayout();
  
  for (var element in children) {
    element.markNeedsLayout();
  }
  //or: individually
  // final renderWidget2 = (childForSlot(WidgetSlot.Widget) as RenderWidget2);
  // renderWidget2.markNeedsLayout();
}
```